# How to get return url from third party used in a frame by using javascrtipt

Tags: javascript, iframe, navigation

We are having a system where user is sent to third party, after successful authorization, that third party provide us a code in the form of return url. How can I get that return url using javascript? The third party url looks like,

```
var authorizedurl = "https://secure.stitch.money/connect/authorize?client_id=" + "test-abc-dsf-4bfd-8e0d-ec21bec1f2ff" + "&scope=openid accounts balances transactions accountholders client_imageupload client_paymentrequest paymentinitiationrequest client_paymentauthorizationrequest client_refund client_disbursement&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://localhost:8000/return&state=" + state + "&nonce=" + nonce + "&code_challenge=" + chal + "&code_challenge_method=S256";
```

and after successful authorization, it will return a url like -

```
"https://localhost:8000/return?code=-s4ZFeOn2UqtNrErck0k5bP_wtfMlU0B8JuXjTbj_WpyY&scope=openid%20accounts%20balances%20transactions%20accountholders%20client_imageupload%20client_paymentrequest%20paymentinitiationrequest%20client_paymentauthorizationrequest%20client_refund%20client_disbursement&state=u7mceUJemzF6UdgFzJFNKiTkfWGfzBGqTpSvA41ZPj0&session_state=4rBBhSntSGVHxpKI3ivtTceZkFAicUQLxWFinfKjwnc.ylgY-Q05H8GSX9jfDpmBsQ"
```

we need to get that code parameter from the above url. But iframe does not allow us to fetch navigated url.

The third party url looks like,

````
var authorizedurl = "https://secure.stitch.money/connect/authorize?client_id=" + "test-abc-dsf-4bfd-8e0d-ec21bec1f2ff" + "&scope=openid accounts balances transactions accountholders client_imageupload client_paymentrequest paymentinitiationrequest client_paymentauthorizationrequest client_refund client_disbursement&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://localhost:8000/return&state=" + state + "&nonce=" + nonce + "&code_challenge=" + chal + "&code_challenge_method=S256";```

```and after successful authorization, it will return a url like -
"https://localhost:8000/return?code=-s4ZFeOn2UqtNrErck0k5bP_wtfMlU0B8JuXjTbj_WpyY&scope=openid%20accounts%20balances%20transactions%20accountholders%20client_imageupload%20client_paymentrequest%20paymentinitiationrequest%20client_paymentauthorizationrequest%20client_refund%20client_disbursement&state=u7mceUJemzF6UdgFzJFNKiTkfWGfzBGqTpSvA41ZPj0&session_state=4rBBhSntSGVHxpKI3ivtTceZkFAicUQLxWFinfKjwnc.ylgY-Q05H8GSX9jfDpmBsQ
````

Comment: Read the url in the iframe and use `postMessage` to send it to the parent

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but when I try to read iframe url, it shows following error -
"blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame."